# R: rank with ties.method = average not showing ranks with decimals

Tags: r, average, rank

I have a dataset which ranks a column according to values. I am using `rank` with the `ties.method = c("average")` method. It seems as though using the averaging of the rank behaves differently to my expectation.

I experimented with 4 datasets:

1:

`structure(list(X1.4 = c(1, 2, 2, 2, 4)), row.names = c(NA, 5L
), class = "data.frame")`

2:

`structure(list(X1.4 = c(1, 2, 2, 4)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")`

3:

`structure(list(X1.6 = c(1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3)), row.names = c(NA, 
7L), class = "data.frame")`

4:
`structure(list(X1.8 = c(1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 8)), row.names = c(NA, 
-8L), class = "data.frame")`

When I used the `rank` with `ties.method = c("average")`, they resulted in:

1 `rank(x, ties.method = c("average"))`:

`X1.4 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> 
   1    3    3    3    5`

2 `rank(y, ties.method = c("average"))`:

`X1.4 <NA> <NA> <NA> 
 1.0  2.5  2.5  4.0`

3 `rank(z, ties.method = c("average"))`:

`X1.6 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> 
   1    4    4    4    4    4    7`

4 `X1.8 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> 
 1.0  4.5  4.5  4.5  4.5  4.5  4.5  8.0`:

My first instinct is that ties with a even number result in averaging with decimals bc they break cleanly into `.5`s. I would like to find a way for the odd number of ties to still show the decimals.

For example, I would expect #1 to be:

`X1.4 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> 
   1    2.33    2.33    2.33    5`

Is this possible? Thanks.

Comment: Not clear what rule you'd like the ranking to follow. To be clear on the "average" method you show, the first is 3 because that's what `mean(c(2, 3, 4))` is (i.e. the mean of the tied-ranks). The next is 2.5 because that's what `mean(c(2, 3))` (i.e. the mean of the tied ranks). Same for the others. So it's not that there's decimals in the result but they aren't being shown, it's just that the "average" method for those cases results in an integer rank.

Comment: Yes, but is there a way for the average method to show cases not as integers but as numerics?

Comment: @IceCreamToucan Actually thank for you clarifying this for me. I was confused as to how the rank function worked...I was averaging the values of the records no the ranks themselves which led me to confuse myself.